# Is there anything that makes VM wares different to normal OS for virus scanners?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, anti-virus

As I'm often using VM wares for my job I stumbled a few times over a problem with the virus scanner I'm using (Avast).

It works normally on my PC, but whenever I'm working from inside a VM Ware and am trying to download something (for example mozilla or visual studio) I need to deactivate the virus scanner, as else it "blocks" the download (without saying something, just reducing the download speed to 0bytes/sec).

As I've noticed this now time and again (while on a normal PC nothing of that sort). I'm wondering there, if from a virus scanners perspective something is different inside a VM to outside of it?

Comment: Yes;  It is trivial, to write code, to detect if the program you wrote is running within a virtual machine.

Comment: @rambound I know that as its the bios even that is called differently (special) inside of VMs..... still though the question is if from the perspective of a virus scanner something is different (aside from them checking if its a vm or not...which I don't think would bring them anything thus questionable if they do that), as the behavior I noticed is not what is to be expected.